# Trouble with operation

Tags: c

So I am making a Caesar cipher program I have the encryption working just fine it is the decryption I am having trouble with.

Here is the code that works for encryption on uppercase letters:

```
        if (isupper(p[i])){
    char c = ((p[i] - 'A') + k % 26) + 'A';
     }
```

Now I would think that decryption would be:

```
        if (isupper(pp[i])){
    char c = (abs((p[i] - 'A') - k) % 26) + 'A';
     }
```

The issue that I'm having is that if k=1 and p[i]='A' it will just output the letter 'B' and not 'Z' it does not wrap around like it should so if k=2 and p[i]='A' it should output the letter 'Y'. It works if k=1 and p[i]='B' it will output 'A' thanks for any help.

Comment: That `abs` probably shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if (isupper(p[i])){
    char c = (p[i] - 'A' + 26 - k) % 26) + 'A';
}
```

The `+ 26` gives you your wrapping

Think of it this way (the three digit number format is just to make things line up nicely):

```
| 000 | 001 | 002 | ... | 024 | 025 | plain
|  A  |  B  |  C  | ... |  Y  |  Z  |
| 003 | 004 | 005 | ... | 001 | 002 | crypto
```

Now, recognize that

```
(n + 26) % 26 === (n % 26)
```

So:

```
| 000 | 001 | 002 | ... | 024 | 025 | plain
|  A  |  B  |  C  | ... |  Y  |  Z  |
| 029 | 030 | 031 | ... | 053 | 054 | crypto
```

is equivalent to the above when you consider modulo 26

This makes life a lot easier. The plaintext symbol set is made up of a contiguous set of integers from `'A'` to `'A' + 25`. The problem is that the ciphertext symbol set is not contiguous... there's a discontinuity at `025`. By adding 26, you can convert the cipher text to a contiguous range from `'A' + k + 26` to `'A' + k + 49`.

It's *much* easier then to map your contiguous ciphertext symbol set to your plaintext symbol set.

Since the Caesar code could be a shift in either direction and the decrypt is just the opposite shift, you could combine this to

```
boolean decrypt;
int k; 
...
k = k % 26; // Ensure that the shift doesn't include any wrapping
if(decrypt) {
    k *= -1;
}
if (isupper(p[i])){
    char c = (p[i] - 'A' + 26 + k) % 26) + 'A';
}
```

Comment: Together with wallyk's fix for the encryption, that is it.

Comment: Thanks for the help that was the fix i needed

Answer (score 0):

In the encryption,

```
((p[i] - 'A') + k % 26) + 'A'
```

consider that it is evaluated as

```
t1 = p[i] - 'A'
t2 = k % 26
result = t1 + t2 + 'A'
```

That probably is not what you intended.  The decryption would not reverse that arithmetic, mostly because the extra grouping changes the order of operations.

Comment: My bad I was using the wrong operation for encryption this is what worked for encryption

if (isupper(p[i])){
 char c = ('A' + (((p[i] - 'A') + k ) % 26));
   printf("%c", c);
     }

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering the fact that they wrap around, try it like this:

```
if ((p[i] - 'A' - k) < 0 )
    c = 'Z' - (abs(p[i] - 'A' - k) % 26) + 1;
else 
    c = (abs(p[i] - 'A' - k) % 26) + 'A';
```

And I think you don't need the moudulo "%" either.